# How to make all keyframe scene visible objects, visible in the renderer for each keyframe

Tags: rendering, scripting, objects

I need urgent help on this for a project that's due. I didn't know there was a camera renderer that also need to be altered i thought it was scene view the whole time. (there's probably a script that does the job,but i can't find it), so all my objects that weren't meant to be visible all show at the start and i could go to that small camera icon each time and set the visibility keyframe manually but it would take way too long.
I have camera, texts from blender, plane from blender, plane with images and a armature installed from https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/76197

[image: DopeSheet showing all the objects used]
Here are all the objects in the dopesheet. At the moment all i could think of to solve this problem would be scripting,but the documentation is bad, so i need expertise.

Comment: what do you have keyframed? add a picture of your scene so we get an idea of what you are working with.

Comment: Done, anymore information i could be unaware of?

Comment: That picture is not really what I meant. I meant the 3d view. I still dont understand why you cant see the objects when looking through your camera. What do you have keyframed on the camera?

Comment: I have the position and orthographic scale keyframed, but it has nothing to do with the camera, it works perfectly in scene view when played. The problem is. That i didn't account for that small camera icon in the outliner, so i could right click it and keyframe visibility. ( i thought it was that small eye icon).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Someone could have mentioned a quick fix... the openGL renderer uses the scene view and i spent the whole of last night trying to figure out ways until today. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/42532)

Comment: I am the author (stop picking on newbies)